# Visual Studio Professional 2012 & InstallShield 2012 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield

I have a project created in Visual Studio 2012. The installer was made using InstallShield LE

Due to shortcomings a copy of InstallShield professional was provided when I was asked to take over the project.

After installing it shows up in VS 2008 but not 2012.
When I attempt to open the project it informs me isproj is not supported (I didn't bother installing LE first).
I also have no InstallShield options upon attempting to create a new project.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: You tend to not get answers for problems with 3rd party programs and utilities around here.  You might get lucky, but using the vendor's support channels is the best way to get accurate help.  Providing them with repro steps is usually required, they'll need to know exactly what you did if the problem isn't otherwise common.  It shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks, if I haven't had anything by the end of today I will take a look.
Although it is beginning to look like I have been tasked with using two products that simply don't work together! Oh Joy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield 2012 (released in 2011) did not come with support for Visual Studio 2012 (released in 2012). InstallShield 2012 Spring SP1 adds this support. (Note that InstallShield 2012 Spring is the major release after InstallShield 2012.)